# Spring not able to instantiate bean if method is transactional

Tags: java, spring, transactions, autowired, spring-bean

I have following interface and its concrete implementation

```
public interface ReportGenerator {
    void generateReport(ReportParameter reportParameter) 
}

@Component
public class ConcreteReportGenerator {
    @Override
    @Transactional //**If concrete method is annotated transaction then bean not instantiating** 
    void generateReport(ReportParameter reportParameter) {
     //Concrete Implementation 
    }
}
```

If annotated with transactional annotation then get following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type[...ConcreteReportGenerator ]
```

without transactional annotation it works fine. Can someone please tell me why it does not initiate with transactional annotation.

Comment: Add your Application Context to the question.

Comment: are you wiring ConcreteReportGenerator in another bean ? when adding @Transactional annotation, spring creates a proxy which implements the class interface. if you try to wire  ConcreteReportGenerator (and not ReportGenerator), you will hit this error.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using CGLib, which is necessary to apply AOP advice to classes rather than interfaces (which can be proxied).

Answer (score 2):

@YairHarel: Yes, i am wiring ConcereteReportGenerator in another bean. if i load bean by class (as mentioned below) then it fails if annotated concrete method transactional:

```
applicationContext.getBean(ConcereteReportGenerator.class)
```

but when i change it to load by name and typecast to interface (**ReportGenerator**) then its working fine

```
(ReportGenerator) applicationContext.getBean("concereteReportGenerator")
```

The below blog explains it very well. if anyone looking for detail see point #5

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception

Comment: Is this an answer? Should it be edit to your question?  I am not sure. (came here as part of review process)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are either missing the bean definition for `Transaction Manager` or does not set it to `annotation-driven`.

Here is how you should be creating Transaction Manager bean in your Application Context:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```